# Word that means approximately "an object that provides emotional comfort" and sounds a bit like "carpenthy"

Tags: single-word-requests

What word that sounds somewhat like "carpenthy" which is used to describe an emotional crutch for example Linus's blanket in Charlie Brown? I feel like I learned a word like this eons ago and poof I can't find it anywhere. Perhaps I dreamed it.

Edit: I found it, see below

Comment: Are you thinking of a [**cathartic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cathartic)? It's a bit strong, though.

Comment: Not quite, the word I am searching for is one that is very rarely used...it would be a word you'd see in a game of Balderdash. I remember reading this word and thinking what a wonderful and specific word. I wish I had a sharper recollection of when I saw it.

Comment: If it came from that game, it might not mean what the person claimed it meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh my gosh I was way off... the word I was looking for was **nepenthe** (nə-ˈpen(t)-thē) which is related to **nepenthean**. I cannot tell you how many obscure word lists I have been looking through. The mind is strange, thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Wow, a wonderful word! I didn't know it, but now I think I won't forget it. Thanks! It's not in _Peanuts_ though, is it?

Comment: **From Poe's** *The Raven*:  
Then, methought, the air grew denser, perfumed from an unseen censer   / 
Swung by Seraphim whose foot-falls tinkled on the tufted floor.  /
    “Wretch,” I cried, “thy God hath lent thee—by these angels he hath sent thee  /
    Respite—respite and **nepenthe** from thy memories of Lenore;  /
Quaff, oh quaff this kind **nepenthe** and forget this lost Lenore!”  /
            Quoth the Raven “Nevermore.”

Answer (score 1):

It seems too obvious given the reference to *Linus's blanket*, but a common term for this is [**security blanket**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/security%20blanket):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : a blanket carried by a child as a protection against anxiety
> **2** : a usually familiar object whose presence dispels anxiety
>
> // Alabama’s receiving corps is the best *security blanket* a new quarterback can ask for, but just how much does the Tide coaching staff trust Jones to throw the ball?
> — C.j. Doon, *baltimoresun.com*, "Can Wisconsin bounce back? Will Auburn hang with LSU? Most intriguing college football questions for Week 9," 25 Oct. 2019

It's the second sense that has a broader application.

---

To address a comment, I find the words *security* and *carpenthy* to sound very similar. I might use them in a rhyme:

> "My blanket offers not carpenthy, but instead provides security."

Comment: _Security Blanket_ doesn't sound like _carpenthy_ to me??

Comment: @Conrado *Security* and *carpenthy* sound very similar to me. I would use them in a rhyme.

Comment: well, put that way... I guess you're right.

Comment: @Conrado I agree with you. Other than ending in the same vowel sound, they sound nothing alike.  Different number of syllables, none of other syllables are rhymes, let alone exact matches

Comment: The Talmud tells a story of a woman who sent her cook to market for a colander but warns her not to buy anything with holes. If I were the cook, I'd ignore what the boss asked and bring back what the boss *wants*. There's a parallel here.